# How to parse an image that was just uploaded to make sure it doesn't contain malicious code?

Tags: uploads, security

Let's assume that an user has just uploaded an image. How do we make sure that the **image doesn't contain hidden PHP code that will run once the image is on the server?** The most common (and, for practical purposes, the only one) attack pattern is to include some PHP code in your `.jpg` file(s) and upload them. Let's assume this is a POST REST endpoint, call it `upload_image`, we're trying to simply ping it, by providing the image. For simplicity's sake, let's assume that our image is `base64` encoded.

The system will decode it, see that it's a `.jpg` and try to run `media_handle_sideload`. All we're doing is uploading a file on the server. No checks.

I have searched far and wide for a WP-based solution, both on Google and on Github, and it seems there's none, or no consensus on how to do it. Looking at `async-upload.php` and `media.php`, it doesn't seem that they do any checks at all. It is assumed that, if an user can upload images, he's to be trusted. I can't see any parsing/checking.

What should I do?

Comment: Is this in reference to a specific vulnerability? On premise, I would think something would have to instruct PHP to try and interpret the image or some meta-data as PHP instead of handling it as generic binary data - and I can't imagine why WordPress would do any such thing to begin with.

Comment: @bosco It's absolutely trivial to include a shell via metadata. PHP, on its own, does nothing to prevent such injections.

Comment: I still don't understand... I think you're saying you can set up an image as a CGI script? Sure - but it still doesn't matter if nothing attempts to execute it as such. WordPress won't. An end-user requesting the file won't (unless the webserver's misconfigured, perhaps, or you've allowed users to upload files with extensions which a server would execute). Could you include a link to the specific vulnerability (or write-up or something - just more information regarding what an answer needs to address)?

Comment: @bosco Perhaps am worrying too much. Sorry, I thought it doesn't need any explanation, given it's a pretty standard attack vector, and a common one at that - https://onestepcode.com/injecting-php-code-to-jpg/ , as well as https://www.trustwave.com/en-us/resources/blogs/spiderlabs-blog/hiding-php-code-in-image-files-revisited/ . Provided, the extension attacks are something rare, given most Apache configurations solve it from the get-go. In our case, WordPress does check against it through our MIME types, but I don't see anything for metadata.

Comment: I admit I'm not well versed when it comes to PHP vulnerabilities as a whole. And I am totally behind the mindset that we could and should secure everything which we can, because "the minimum necessary security" is not security at all. I really do appreciate your mindset here and the intent of the question, whole-heartedly - where it comes to security, I'm not sure if we can really "worry too much" :). But in providing what specifically we're up against, I think this question will solicit better answers. WordPress does strip meta-data from thumbnails - but not the original. It could be better